# Android retrofit, serializing POST parameters

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit to Post form data and recieve back XML. What I have so far works fine but i want to make some changes. Here is my existing code (and it works):

Here is my interface

```
public interface SignupUser
{
      @FormUrlEncoded
      @POST("/createaccount.cfm")
      SignupServerResponse signup(@Field("e") String email, @Field("p") String password);
}
```

Here is the code to call the api (again, this works fine, I will explain below what I want to change)

```
SignUpDetails mDeets; // this gets initialize and set somewhere else


RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://myurl.com")
            .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter()).build(); // the response is xml, that works fine

SignupUser service = restAdapter.create(SignupUser.class);

SignupServerResponse res = service.signup(mDeets.getE(), mDeets.getP());
```

How can I make it so that I can pass the SignUpDetails object straight to the signup() method instead of passing in separate Strings? When I change the constructor of signup() to accept SignUpdetails object (see below) and pass my SignUpDetails object in, I get an error saying

> No Retrofit Annotation Found

Here is how I would like to define the interface

```
public interface SignupUser
{
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/createaccount.cfm")
        SignupServerResponse signup(SignUpDetails deets);
}
```

And call it like this (instead of passing in all those parameters)

```
SignupServerResponse res = service.signup(mDeets);
```

I tried adding @Field above each of my variables in the SignUpDetails class and that doesnt work either (compilation error)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same.

Answer (score -1):

On your interface use @Body annotation for the deets parameter:

```
@POST("/createaccount.cfm")
SignupServerResponse signup(@Body SignUpDetails deets);
```

That should convert SignUpDetails into XML (since you use xml converter on your adapter).
It is then your responsibility to parse the XML request body on server.

Comment: I dont want to convert the SignUpDetails object (post params) to xml, I am posting form data. ( its the Server response that is mxl. that works fine already)